# .net mvc5 show distinct elements in select

Tags: .net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on a web application using .net MVC5 framework. My view gets information from the model and displays a building type and the number of floors in two separate select elements. However, I need to only display unique building type and number of floors information. Below if the image of the issue[image: ![]

I am not sure how to do this. Here's the code for that page:

```
@model IEnumerable<BIRDSResidential.Models.ResidentialBuilding>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ResidentialBuilding";
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <select>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <option value="">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.type)</option>
            }
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <select>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <option value="">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.stories)</option>
            }
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-offset-5 col-md-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div
```

>

**EDIT**

I updated the code above to the following:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        @Html.DropDownList("ResidentialBuilding", new SelectList(Model.Select(x => x.type).Distinct()))
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        @Html.DropDownList("ResidentialBuilding", new SelectList(Model.Select(x => x.stories).Distinct()))
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        @Html.DropDownList("ResidentialBuilding", new SelectList(Model.Select(x => x.size)))
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

This renders the information appropriately, but does not add any value attributes to the option elements. If I use the line (shown below) in the controller, the distinct option does not work, but values are added to the option tags. Any leads?

```
//ViewBag.ResidentialBuildings = new SelectList(db.ResidentialBuildings, "ID", "type");
```

Comment: `@foreach (var item in Model.Select(x => x.type).Distinct())`? Also, are you aware of the `Html.DropDownListFor` helper?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Distinct items should be just a matter of using the LINQ extensions `.Distinct` (coupled with using `.Select` to distill down to types only). e.g.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Select(x => x.type).Distinct())
{
    <option value="">@Html.DisplayFor(x => item)</option>
}
```

However, I'd look at using the `Html.DropDownList` helper to make life easier:

```
@Html.DropDownList("", new SelectList(Model.Select(x => x.type).Distinct()))
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you guys know of any good tutorials that could possibly help me with this?